# Ejecutar función al hacer click en notificación

Tags: android, firebase-messaging

Estoy creando una notificación, deseo que al hacer click en ella se ejecute una función.

```
//CREO EL CANAL

fun createNotificationChannel(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

            val channel: NotificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId,channelName, importance)

            val manager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
```

Uso firebaseMessaging para enviar la notificación, luego para mostrarla cuando la app esta en primer plano uso lo siguiente.

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {

        App.getMainActivity()?.showNotify(p0.notification?.title.toString(),
            p0.notification?.body.toString()

//Extraigo el titulo y contenido luego los envió como parámetro para que se cree la notificación.
        )
   
    }

}


  fun showNotify(tlNtf:String,ctnNtf:String){
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channelId).also {
            it.setContentTitle(tlNtf)
            it.setContentText(ctnNtf)
            it.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_fg)
            it.color = Color.RED 
            it.priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH

        }.build()
        val notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notification)
    }
```

Necesito que al hacer click en la notificación se ejecute una función, he leído la documentación sin embargo no encontré nada acerca de eso, se que se puede abrir una actividad con un intent, sin embargo solo necesito que ejecute una función de la actividad en la que me encuentro.

Además no tiendo  por que la notificación no se muestra arriba de la pantalla es decir, llega correctamente pero se va directamente al panel de notificaciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplos de como debería aparecer según un codelab, no aparece de esta forma solo aparece directamente en el panel de notificacion, hay algo que este asiendo mal?

Comment: Procura nombrar las cosas de manera que otros también puedan entenderlas. En vez de poner "tlNtf" y "ctnNtf" podrías llamarlas "title" y "body". Queda mucho mas claro e incluso es más corto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar extras en el intent que te sirvan de indicador para saber si la activity fue abierta desde una notificación

```
fun showNotify(tlNtf: String, ctnNtf: String) {
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("ejecutarFuncion", true)
    }
    val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        NOTIFICATION_ID,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId).apply {
        setContentTitle(tlNtf)
        setContentText(ctnNtf)
        setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_fg)
        color = Color.RED
        priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH
    }.build()
    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
}
```

Luego en tu activity evaluas si el extra existe y ejecutas la función

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        if (intent.hasExtra("ejecutarFunction")) doSomething()
    }

    fun doSomething() {}

}
```

Para casos simples como el ejemplo anterior ni siquiera necesitas consultar el valor del extra pero si quieres ejecutar distintas funciones, deberás leer el valor. Por ejemplo así

Intent

```
putExtra("function", "fun2")
```

Activity

```
if (intent.hasExtra("function")) {
    when (intent.getStringExtra("function")) {
        "fun1" -> function1()
        "fun2" -> function2()
        "fun3" -> function3()
    }
}
```